# iOS XCODE on ipa generation says symbols not found for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, iphone

on running command  from terminal  `lipo -info /_PATH/XYZ_LIB.framework/XYZ_LIB` tells that
it supports armv7 arm64  as output on terminal is

```
Architectures in the fat file: /_PATH/XYZ_LIB.framework/XYZ_LIB are: armv7 arm64
```

But on generating ipa it says symbols not found for architecture armv7.
What can be the probable cause?

Comment: In Xcode, hold the option key and select Product / Clean Build Folder. Then rebuild. I've had this exact problem and this "deep clean" resolves it for me. Also, ensure that for your Pods project that the build setting for Build Active Architecture Only is set to NO.